# encryption and decryption of fields using callback in model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

I have used before_create callback function to encrypt email field before saving.
Similarly, now i want to decrypt them in model before using it in action for display.

What should be used for this?

Can i use afer_save callback method?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343996/rails-storing-encrypted-data-in-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar case is described here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

```
class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_save      EncryptionWrapper.new
   after_save       EncryptionWrapper.new
   after_initialize EncryptionWrapper.new
end

class EncryptionWrapper
  def before_save(record)
    record.credit_card_number = encrypt(record.credit_card_number)
  end

  def after_save(record)
    record.credit_card_number = decrypt(record.credit_card_number)
  end

  alias_method :after_find, :after_save

  private
    def encrypt(value)
      # Secrecy is committed
    end

    def decrypt(value)
      # Secrecy is unveiled
    end
end
```

Comment: Is it saving the encrypted value in database?

Comment: Yes, encrypts just before it writes to the db.